# What ARIA state role to use for current page in navigation

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

Recently I've been implementing ARIA into a web application and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279113/recommended-wai-aria-implementation-for-navigation-bar-menu) to be quite helpful in the improving the navigation parts.

After implementing this in all modules, I discovered this HTML validation error:

> Attribute `aria-selected` not allowed on element `a` at this point.

Looking at the ARIA specification, I see that `aria-selected` is only used in roles gridcell, option, row, and tab. In my case, the role of the link is `menuitem`.

This is a representative sample of the HTML code:

```
<nav role=navigation>
    <ul role=menubar>
        <li role=presentation><a href='page1.php' role=menuitem>Page 1</a></li>
        <li role=presentation><a href='page2.php' role=menuitem>Page 2</a></li>
        <li role=presentation><a href='page3.php' role=menuitem aria-selected=true>Page 3</a></li>
        <li role=presentation><a href='page4.php' role=menuitem>Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, this is taken on "page 3".

What is the correct ARIA role to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that aria-selected is for 'widgets' that are one-tab stop, like a set of tabs that you then arrow around to select. The selected aspect is about **which one is in focus**, *not* which page you are on.

I would check out this as a well tested example:
http://whatsock.com/tsg/Coding%20Arena/ARIA%20Menus/Horizontal%20(Internal%20Content)/demo.htm

From: http://whatsock.com/tsg/

For showing the current page I would probably use a more traditional method: Make it not a link. E.g:

```
<li><a href='page2.php'>Page 2</a></li>
<li><strong>Page 3</strong></li>
```

This also prevents people from clicking on the same-page link by accident (which I see quite often in usability testing). You can apply the same CSS to `nav ul a` and `nav ul strong` and then override the styling for the strong.

Comment: That answers the question about what `aria-selected` is for, but not "how to identify which page I am on". Interesting demo nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, ok, I've added something about current page, does that help?

Answer (score 4):

you may also use `aria-current="page"` for describing current displayed page among navigation items.

Comment: See for some further explanation: https://tink.uk/using-the-aria-current-attribute/

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** you can use `aria-current="page"` or `aria-current="location"` to indicate the current link in a list of links.

Your pagination component could be improved in terms of accessibility (you can see this as a variation of the similar [breadcrumbs pattern](https://www.aditus.io/patterns/breadcrumbs/)):

```html
<nav aria-label="pagination">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/results/1">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/results/2">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/results/3" aria-current="location">Page 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/results/4">Page 4</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

A few notes:

- Use `<nav>` to automatically use the navigation landmark (`<nav>` is equivalent to `<div role="navigation">` but shorter and more elegant)
- Use `aria-label` to provide a meaningful name to the `<nav>` (most likely, you have more `<nav>` elements on the page and you should label each one accordingly).
- Use  to make the set of links structured. This can also help screen reader users as it will be announced as **"pagination, navigation (next) list, 4 items**, helping users understand how many pages there are.
- Use aria-current="location"`or`aria-current="page"` current page of the list (this is most likely shown in a different style as the other pages, but we need to mark it for screen reader users).