# Should I not use aria-current="page" on ancestor link of current page in navbar?

Tags: html, wai-aria

With it being a common practice to highlight a link in the main navbar of a website when viewing the page or subpage of said link, would it be a bad use of `aria-current="page"` to highlight the ancestor link in the navbar on a subpage?

For example, let's say I'm visiting `/galleries/gallery1/`. Could the navbar on that subpage of `galleries` be presented as:

```html
<!-- /galleries/gallery1/index.html -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/galleries/" aria-current="page">Galleries</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or would that be an incorrect usage of `aria-current`?

Comment: That's a perfect way to use it. If your main menu displays the "galleries" link in a different visual style than the other links in the menu (eg, diff background color or "galleries" is underlined), then the sighted user has a clue as to which page corresponds with the menu. That same clue needs to be provided to assistive technology and that's done with `aria-current`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer here: [What ARIA state role to use for current page in navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604677/what-aria-state-role-to-use-for-current-page-in-navigation)

As well as the aria breadcrumbs example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-current

> When you have a group of related elements, such as several links in a
> breadcrumb or steps in a multi-step flow, with one element in the
> group styled differently from the others to indicate to the sighted
> user that this is the current element within its group, the
> aria-current should be used to inform the assistive technology user
> what has been indicated via styling.

I do believe that `aria-current` is designed for non primary navigations like breadcrumbs.

You can leave the active tab non hyperlinked or leave it as is.

Just make sure you use: `role="navigation"` on your nav.