# html <header role="menubar"> not validating on w3 validator

Tags: html, accessibility, backwards-compatibility, w3c-validation, wai-aria

I have this main header element that is a page-specific navigation menu. As you can see the h1 element is a link to (the menu is fixed to the top of the page while the rest scrolls down).

Example:

```
<header role="menubar">
    <a href="#top">
        <h1>Main Title</h1>
    </a>
    <ul role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#presentation">presentation</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#picture">picture</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#downloads">downloads</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

on [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) I get as message:

> Error: Bad value menubar for attribute role on element header.

.

referring me to the [W3 recommendation page for single pages](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-header-element) where the allowed ARIA roles for the header element are:

> banner role (default - do not set) or presentation.

.

'default - do not set' isn't really an option as it would not be backwards compatible because of the header element

'banner' and 'presentation' are not the correct roles (see [banner](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#banner) and [presentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation))

So my questions:

- What do I have to do? Easiest would be to replace the header element
  by a div element. But I think it is semantically less good, is that
  right?
- Is it possible that this case was not really considered by the W3C
  people or is it 100% wrong to do so (I mean on a semantic level
  focusing on accessibility).
- Are there other options?

thank you :)

Comment: Hi @ChristopheStrobbe,  
Thank you for your fast comment. I posted a simplified version of the menu, without the states and properties, only the roles, because that was my concern.
Anyway, you answered my question, by pointing the nav way. I thought that a nav element should only have links to other pages, but checking the W3C page of that element I see that it may also contain links to parts within the page. 

A pity though that it can not be a header, as I still think that, from a semantic point of view, header is more correct than nav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your current code shows is not a menubar but a navigation list. Instead of `<header role="menubar">` you need `<nav>` and you should remove the role attributes from the list elements. If you are implementing a menu bar, your code is very incomplete.

For advice on using HTML5 and WAI-ARIA for menu bars, see [Recommended WAI-ARIA implementation for navigation bar/menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279113/recommended-wai-aria-implementation-for-navigation-bar-menu).